# Trying to use nextRowset to get two results

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to store two results in two variables but I can not get it to work:

```
$sql->query('SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * from table2;');
$first = $sql->getAllData();
$second = $sql->nextRowset()->getAllData();
```

How should I use this instead?

edit: function:

```
public function getAllData()
{
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```